# Protection Level making a variable Inaccessible

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to work with Unity and C# to make a first person game. Using one of my own created scripts, I am trying to access the Run speed and Walk speed variables from the stock "FirstPersonController".

I have changed the needed variables to Public, and I can even see them in the property inspector window, but my own script is unable to access them, with the following errors :

1) Unable to access the variables Run and Walk speeds.

```
Assets/PlayerVitals.cs(134,30): error CS0122: `UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson.FirstPersonController.m_RunSpeed' is inaccessible due to its protection level
```

2) Unable to access a variable I added to FirstPersonController, claiming it does not exist (Even though it shows in the Unity Property Inspector - Screenshot Attached)

```
Assets/PlayerVitals.cs(134,60): error CS1061: Type `UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson.FirstPersonController' does not contain a definition for `m_NormRunSpeed' and no extension method `m_NormRunSpeed' of type `UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson.FirstPersonController' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
```

The following is the relevant portion of both code :

FirstPersonController.cs :

```
namespace UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson
{
    [RequireComponent(typeof (CharacterController))]
    [RequireComponent(typeof (AudioSource))]
    public class FirstPersonController : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField] private bool m_IsWalking;
        [SerializeField] public float m_WalkSpeed;
        [SerializeField] public float m_RunSpeed;
        [SerializeField] public float m_NormRunSpeed;
```

PlayerVitals.cs :

```
using UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson;

public class PlayerVitals : MonoBehaviour {
public FirstPersonController playerController;
playerController = GetComponent<FirstPersonController>();
.
.
currentSpeed = playerController.m_RunSpeed;
```

[image: Property Inspector]

Comment: I would guess that you are referencing the wrong version (an old one? the release version?, etc..) of the assembly containing these classes somehow in your project.  I would check the path.  Also, normally I go with automatically implemented properties for stuff like this.

Comment: Also thought of:  I've had to restart Visual Studio before for compiler errors like this.  Sometimes it just needs it.

Comment: Wrong version is my thought as well.... how would I be able to check that though? I dragged it straight into the game area from the assets folder, and started editing it right there. Double clicking it in Hierarchy view just links me back to the same script. I can also see the public change in the script preview within Unity itself..

Have also restarted Unity, Visual Studio and my PC several times :(

Comment: Maybe try deleting all the compiled objects and force it to rebuild everything? Basically every `bin` and `obj` folder

Comment: Have you tried to clean up the Library? Close Unity, delete the `Library` directory in your project, and then re-open Unity and let it rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

Found the error. I had made a backup copy of FirstPersonController and even renamed it, but somehow it was causing this problem (Even though it was in a different directory altogether). Deleting it fixed this issue!

Comment: If it was still in the assets folder, Unity would still see it and compile it. Changing the file name has no effect as it would still have the same *Class identifier.*

Comment: I see, that never occurred to me. Thank you!